# Run Android test using emulator using appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I want to run test using the emulator.

I am starting the test and appium logs are below:-

```
 Using adb from /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb
info: Retrieving device
info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/karunakaran/work/software/android_64_bit_linux/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
```

I can able to run test using real device. How can I run test using emulator in linux machine for Android test.

Comment: try restarting emulator

Comment: @Apurva How to start/stop emulator

Comment: close it and open again

Comment: @Apurva Its working now.